# Trigger "click" event in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger a click event in cross domain iframe with javascript or jquery?

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <div id='divA'>
        <button type='button' id='buttonA'>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div id='divB'>
        <iframe name='random'>
            <div role='button' id='buttonB'></div>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Example : 
Trigger click event on div(#buttonB) when user click "buttonA"

Comment: **Short answer**: no

Comment: @Pedram ok, thx for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect click event in cross-domain iframe but one way is that you can detect focus on that iframe.

First click outside of iframe and then on iframe! You will see the alert.

```js
window.focus(); //force focus on the currenct window;
window.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    if(document.activeElement == document.querySelector('iframe'))
    {
        alert('Focus Left Current Window and Moved to Iframe / Possible click!');
    }
});
```

```html
<iframe name='random'>
    <div role='button' id='buttonB'></div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: The iframe is hidden, so user won't be able to see and click the iframe. I want to trigger the click event on a button('buttonB') which inside the iframe when user clicked the button('buttonA') on my page. Thx for sharing btw

Answer (score -3):

```
$('#buttonB').on('click',function(){
    ('#buttonA').click();
});
```